# Multiple android animations don't work at the same time

Tags: java, android, animation

I have `picView.startAnimation(anim);` and `picView.startAnimation(anim2);`, but only `picView.startAnimation(anim2);` works.

When I remove the second animation only `picView.startAnimation(anim);` works.

I want both animations to be running at the same time, what am I doing wrong ?

The code I have

```
public class PicView extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pic_view);

        LinearLayout myLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);

        final ImageView picView = new ImageView(this);
        myLL.addView(picView);

        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        myLL.addView(tv);


        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PicView.this, R.anim.anim_button);
        Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PicView.this, R.anim.anim_button2);
        picView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a0000);
        picView.startAnimation(anim);
        picView.startAnimation(anim2);

    }
}
```

Comment: which object are you trying to animate?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an `AnimationSet`.

Something like this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PicView.this, R.anim.anim_button);
Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PicView.this, R.anim.anim_button2);

AnimationSet as = new AnimationSet(true);
as.addAnimation(anim);
as.addAnimation(anim2);

viewYouWantToAnimate.setAnimation(as);

as.start();
```

Comment: tnx but didn't help me , i tryed on 2.2 and 4.0.3 emulator but it first shows pic whitout any animation for a moment then screen becomes white for about 1.5 second then shows view stayble

Comment: @BehnamRanjbar which object are you trying to animate?